# Androidx Constraintlayout is unresponsive with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout, androidx

I am running into issues with Android Studio 3.3.2 and the AndroidX version of constraint layout. Basically when I converted my Constraint layout to

```
androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha4
```

The editor is not letting me move views around, connect views with `chains/constraints` ..etc. When I do that, I find "Error reported" by Android studio about something crashes. And then the editor becomes unresponsive to changes (say if I change margin from `0dp` to `8dp`). No changes take effect in the editor or xml.

Any ideas what I need to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too faced the same issue,even after invalidating caches and restarting it was not working. So I just migrated to

```
androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3
```

The motionLayout inside alpha4 was also having some problem

Comment: I actually had to go down to version 1.1.3 to get it to work!

Comment: I will try it again. I am 90% sure I tried  but I am.doubting myself now :)

Comment: yeah please comment if it's working because for me its working.